# Conflict with react-native class static and react context(High Order Component)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation, expo

(Clarification i made my app using expo init)

**I was trying to mix firebase and react-native and came across to this problem**

*NavigateScreen.js*

```
 class NavigateScreen extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'Campus Navigator',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#ffa000',
              borderBottomColor: 'black',
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
            },
          };

    ...

    }

    export default withFirebase(NavigateScreen);
```

*context.js*

```
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

basically it passes a firebase instance to a component. but the problem is the static navigationOptions just won't appear on the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher order components does not pass (unless specifically implemented) static navigationOptions to the child component.

You can fix this by using the following structure.

```
const withFirebaseNavigateScreen = withFirebase(NavigateScreen);

withFirebaseNavigateScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Campus Navigator',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffa000',
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
});

export default withFirebaseNavigateScreen;
```